# building a dictionary

Tags: glossaries, dictionaries

sometimes when I am not sure about a term, I would like to write it somewhere with the subsequent definition to be able to re-read it from time to time and then remember it forever. I think I am going to start now using Latex. Should I use the glossary package? I just want something like `\word{term}{definition}` and when compiling, the alphabetical order should be respected. Thanks

Comment: see a coded answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5821/creating-a-standalone-glossary/5837#5837 (substituting `\word` for `\dictentry` where it appears).

Comment: great! working well!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Download the [glossaries](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/) package which is the latest version. It has what you are looking for and will also sort out your definitions in alphabetical order.