# Exit codes of pdfLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, compiling, scripts

In the script I presented in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5821/creating-a-standalone-glossary) I encountered the following problem. In case of a compilation error, I have to cancel the execution of `pdflatex` 3 times. This can be very annoying. I would like to add something like

```
if pdflatex file.tex returned failure break script
```

However, I could find what values `pdflatex` returns when it exits. So the question is:

*What are the exits/return values/codes of `pdflatex`?*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key one for me is that `0` is returned on successful compilation. You don't say what OS you use, so I'll provide a Unix Makefile and a Windows batch file test.  On Unix, I use

```
pdflatex $$NAME
if [ $$? = 0 ] ; then \
  pdflatex $$NAME ; \
  pdflatex $$NAME ; \
else \
 \echo "Compilation failed" ; \
fi
```

On Windows with a batch file the error level test is slightly different

```
pdflatex %1
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  echo ! Compilation failed
) else (
  pdflatex %1
  pdflatex %1
)
```

This tests for failure rather than success as the `if ERRORLEVEL` test works for 'thios number or higher'. You can build quite a lot more complexity on top of this: it depends on your requirements. (For example, my batch file assumes that the name of the file to compile is given as a command-line argument: you might want to use a variable or hard-coded name.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked eventually! Is there some documentation of other return values of pdflatex? This might be helpful...

Comment: Pipelines work more cleanly with Unix exit status codes, I think: compare `(pdflatex $$NAME && pdflatex $$NAME && pdflatex $$NAME) || echo Compilation failed`

Comment: @Charles: I'll take your word for it. (My real Makefile is rather more complex than the example above.)

Comment: @Dror: `0` is a standard value for 'success' from almost all processes.

Comment: @Joseph: I was wondering about other values... Or is it nothing but 0 means success, and 1 failure?

Comment: @Charles: I not using `makefile`, rather a bash script. I'm not sure how to use you advice. I'm laking knowledge in bashing I guess.

Comment: @Dror: (1) the general rule is zero for success, any non-zero for failure.

Comment: @Dror: This part of make is just shell, apart from the doubling of dollar signs: it works fine in Bash if you change the `$$NAME` to `$NAME`.  What I wrote is nearly equivalent to what Joseph wrote: the "&&" joins together two commands (pipelines) where the one on the right executes only if and after the one on the left exits successfully.  The outermost "||"  makes a pipeline where the right executes only if and after the left has failed.  Try it at the command prompt.

Comment: @Charles: I tried it out in my bash script, and it indeed works. However, I find, the if-else way more readable, and I'll use it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4):

Converting Joseph's code into shell syntax, it looks like this:

```
NAME=$1
pdflatex $NAME
if [ $? = 0 ] ; then
  pdflatex $NAME ;
  pdflatex $NAME ;
else 
  echo "Compilation failed" ;
fi
```

I am keying this in as an answer on because of formatting.