# Use TeXShop Preview window when different output-dir is set

Tags: texshop

In TeXShop, under Preferences -> Engines I have modified the LaTeX command by adding `-output-dir=/tmp`.  All of my auxiliary and final output files end up in this directory instead of where my source file is.  That's what I want and this currently works.

However, when output-dir is set as anything, the output pdf does not open in the TeXShop Preview window following a successful typeset.  I can open the pdf manually from /tmp with another pdf viewer.  Also, the **Window-> Source<=>Preview** menu item does nothing.

Is there anyway to restore the automatic Preview functionality in combination with a different output directory?

Comment: I don't know if there is a "built-in" TeXShop solution, but I guess a possible workaround would be to use a custom script that calls pdflatex with `--output-dir=/tmp` and then creates a copy (or a symbolic link) of the output pdf to the original directory (where your source file is).

Comment: I did try creating a symbolic link to the output pdf and synctex files in the 'normal' directory where the latex source is.  No luck though. The pdf preview does not open.

Comment: Then instead of copying the output pdf (let us call it file.pdf), you should probably add `open -a TeXShop /tmp/file.pdf` at the end of your script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me explain a little more the solution suggested in my above comments. In TeXShop, you can choose which "engine" to call when pressing the `Typeset` button. An "Engine“ is basically a shell script which calls standard TeX commands, and sometimes much more (see the TeXShop help panel or [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10039/16873) for instance). In your case, modifying the pdfTeX command in the TeXShop Preferences changes the standard LaTeX engine. As a result of your modification, TeXShop cannot open the PDF preview automatically after typesetting. One way to restore this behaviour is to write a new engine.

To do so, you can simply create a shell script containing the following code

```
#!/bin/bash
pdflatex --output-dir=/tmp "$1"
open -a TeXShop /tmp/$(echo $1 | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1\.pdf/')
```

Make sure the execution bit is active (`chmod +x`), change the extension to `.engine` and move the script to the `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines` folder. Launch TeXShop and select your new engine in the popup menu next to the `Typeset` button, then press `Typeset`.

There may be a more elegant solution, but this works.

Comment: Adding your suggested engine with the open command, the pdf preview does open up in TeXShop.  I also get a second window named for the pdf filename and the typeset action drop-down is set to ConTeXt.  The contents of the second window is empty. I can't seem to sync between pdf and source in the preview window.

Overall this answers the question. Thank you.  I tried, but could not find the built-in .engine / script that TeXShop uses when LaTeX is selected.  I'd be curious to see if the command is the same as what you listed or different.

Answer (score 4):

My solution for this is to use one of the [latexmk](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/) engines.  I then use the following `latexmkrc` file in the directory with my source (`.tex`) file.  (You could also add this to your global `~/latexmkrc` file.):

```
# latexmk Init File; -*-perl-*-
$pdf_mode = 1;
$out_dir = '_build';
mkdir $out_dir;
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex --synctex=1 %O %S; cp %D .';
```

This will first make sure that `$out_dir` (set to `_build` here) exists, then will call `pdflatex` with the `--output-directory=_build` flag (`latexmk` does this).  Finally, after each call to `pdflatex`, the generated `.pdf` file (specified by `%D` will be copied to the current directory, overwriting the local file, triggering [TeXShop](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/)'s previewer to reload the file.  (As the original poster mentioned, creating a symlink is not enough.)

I find this behaviour of copying the generated pdf file out of the `_build` directory to be useful since I usually want to keep it, even when deleting all of the auxilliary files (which is just done by deleting the `_build` directory).

By including the following comment

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
```

at the top of your source (`.tex`) file, you can ensure that [TeXShop](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/) will use the `pdflatexmk` engine by default.

The advantage of this approach is that by distributing the `latexmkrc` file with your `.tex` file, everything will "just work"* for someone using [TeXShop](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/) – even if they forget to select the `pdflatexmk` engine.

<sub>* This will "just work" if [TeXShop](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/) was installed at version 3.07 or later.  Otherwise, you will need to (have your colleagues) copy the inactive `pdflatexmk.engine` file to the active engine directory (note: `~/Library/` is the `Library` folder in the `$HOME` folder, not the system `/Library` folder):</sub>

<sub>`cp ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/Inactive/Latexmk/pdflatexmk.engine ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/`</sub>

### See Also

- [latexmk](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/)
- [TeXShop](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/)
- [all-in-one-engine for TeXShop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41271)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer before, I found that a file name of `platexmkrc` (The character "p" is important here) is required, by which everything works as expected from within `TexShop`. This detail is explained in a file `TexShop/Engines/Inactive/Latexmk/Latexmk For TeXShop.pdf` by Herbert Schulz (herbs2@mac.com), also referenced in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41271/all-in-one-engine-for-texshop) answer.

I found out, because `latexmk -commands` responded by `To run pdflatex, I use 'pdflatex -synctex=1 -halt-on-error %O %S; cp %D .'`, but TeXShop completely ignored this line in the `latexmkrc` (although it accounted for the other lines, creating a new directory and putting files in the directory defined by `$out_dir = '_build';` in the `latexmkrc`).
Therefore I have both files now, a `latexmkrc` and a `platexmkrc`.

I run

- `Latexmk, John Collins, 19 Jan. 2017. Version 4.52c`
- `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017)`
- `TeXShop Version 3.62 (3.62)`

(This is my first post ever, so I couldn't edit/comment)