Creating a dictionary
I'm trying to make a dictionary of terms which can include images or tables. My first idea was to use the glossaries package. I should clarify that I need it's a dictionary and glossaries package seems to need use \gls command to create entries. I only need the entries, my document doesn't include references to words, so I'm not going to use \gls. I've seen other examples and templates, but I have many entries and I'd like they sort themselves and by sections (maybe). In particular, the example is so much complicated for me. I would like something simple.
My attemps was the next:
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, natbib=true, style=apa, hyperref=true, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[automake,toc]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=LaTeX,
    description={Un sistema de preparación de documentos de alta calidad; es especialmente adecuado para la producción de documentos técnicos y científicos}
}

\newglossaryentry{glosario}
{
    name=Glosario,
    description={Una lista de términos con sus respectivas definiciones, usualmente al final de un documento}
}
    
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\title{Illustrated glossary}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter


\chapter{Protista}

\gls{glosario}

\gls{latex}

\chapter{Poríferos}

\gls{glosario}

\gls{latex}

\chapter{Celentéreos}

\gls{glosario}

\gls{latex}

\printglossary

\end{document}


But I want to get is something similar to this:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=LaTeX,
    description={Un sistema de preparación de documentos de alta calidad; es especialmente adecuado para la producción de documentos técnicos y científicos}
}

\newglossaryentry{glosario}
{
    name=Glosario,
    description={Una lista de términos con sus respectivas definiciones, usualmente al final de un documento}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \title{Glosario de Términos}
    \author{Tú}
    \date{\today}
    \maketitle
    
\chapter*{Protista}
    \section*{G}
    \begin{description}
        \item[Glosario] \glsdesc{glosario}
    \end{description}
    
    \section*{L}
    \begin{description}
        \item[LaTeX] \glsdesc{latex}
    \end{description}
    
\chapter*{Celentéreos}
\section*{G}
\begin{description}
    \item[Glosario] \glsdesc{glosario}
\end{description}

\section*{L}
\begin{description}
    \item[LaTeX] \glsdesc{latex}
\end{description}
    
    \clearpage
    \printglossary
    
\end{document}


I don't really know how to get it, or even if it's possible. If there's other package which can sort the terms in a similar way, it would be useful too. Thanks in advance

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5821/creating-a-standalone-glossary (from the list of related questions on the right of the page) seems close.
